# what is server.mappath(".") in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What is server.MapPath() in asp.net.
Can any one please explain with example  written in Vb.net

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Server.MapPath(".")` represents the current request absolute path, so if `Server.MapPath("~")` equals `c:\wwwroot` which represents the site root and the current request is `/foo` then `Server.MapPath(".")` will return `c:\wwwroot\foo`.

Comment: . thank you darin but there is one more question comes out that is what is server.MapPath("~").. whats it purpose...!               Thankyou

Comment: @Mihir, it is used to determine the absolute path of the site root on the file system.

Comment: @Darin..thank you. please find this line.. The path passed to the MapPath method must be an application-relative path rather than an absolute path. this is found in microsoft site. you are saying absolute path but microsoft saying relative path..can u plz explain diiference

Comment: @Mihr, it is the argument which is relative path, the function returns the corresponding physical absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

For detailed explanation, read [`Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths by Rick Strahl`](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx)